# Built static libcurl.a on OS X 10.11, but can't find libcurl.a

Tags: xcode, macos, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to build a static SSL-enabled libcurl.a on OS X 10.11 (TO TARGET 10.8):

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.8"
./configure --disable-shared --with-darwinssl
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

But despite no errors (a few warnings), I can't locate anywhere on the hard disk where a new libcurl.a has been built.  What am I missing?

Daniel solved the problem -- I haven't done Make Install...

FOLLOW-UP:

My whole purpose for building a libcurl.a with --disable-share was to break the dependency on the libcurl.4.dylib.  But just **linking with libcurl.a** creates a dependency to /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib.

See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35566824/1499690) for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need sudo to make nor make clean
2. You're supposed to run `make install` to install the newly built stuff, and then it'll install under /usr/local by default - which you can change with configure's --prefix option
3. After `make install` with default path, the lib will be in /usr/local/lib. Or $prefix/lib really since you can alter the prefix.
4. Before you invoke `make install`, the static library is usually found in the lib/.libs subdirectory.

Comment: Thanks Daniel -- I know you're pretty expert about CURL.

Comment: The proper installed location should be /usr/local/lib (and include/curl), right?  Not opt/local/lib?

Comment: Might not be the right place to ask, but I added a FOLLOW UP into the original question....

Comment: A static libcurl.a does not depend on any shared libcurl library, then something is seriously wrong.

Comment: Just including the properly configured and built libcurl.a in the build target creates that dependency on Libcurl.4.dylib I can see in the compiled app using otool.  Do I need to explicitly REMOVE any protocols that might be pulling it in?

Comment: Moving this to a new question.