# Why adding static libcurl.a to xcode 7.2 example project will add a libcurl.4.dylib dependency

Tags: c++, xcode, curl, linker, xcode7

I had been trying to eliminate any dependency on libcurl.4.dylib by adding libcurl.a to my Xcode 7.2 project.  I had built a brand-new libcurl and placed it in /usr/local/lib (with the header in /usr/local/include/curl):

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.8"
./configure --disable-shared --with-darwinssl
make clean
make
make install
```

But the .app was STILL linked with a dependency on libcurl.4.dylib.  Finding out why took several days.

Although I am adding libcurl.a to my Xcode "Link Binary with Libraries" Build Phase, Xcode's generated link command of -lcurl is telling the linker to,
by default, link with a DYNAMIC library.  The linker will NOT accept
-static as a prefix to -l, because the CLANG driver doesn't support
turning on/off -static/-dynamic on a per-file basis (if the linker does see -static, it expects that EVERYTHING is static — which Apple STRONGLY DISCOURAGES).

Once I changed (in a MANUAL shell link line) the Xcode-generated -lcurl to be explicitly "/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a", the linked .app no longer showed a dependency on libcurl.4.dylib.

What sucks is that it appears there is no easy method to do this through
Xcode — unless I make a copy of libcurl.a with a DIFFERENT NAME.

Maybe others know the "magic" params / build options for Xcode 7.2, or have more insight, but I wanted to leave this here in case anyone else ran into this issue with libcurl -- or any other static (.a) library where there happened to be a dynamic (.dylib) of the same name in the same location.

Stephen

EDIT: This is the command line(s) I used to build the universal static library:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.10"
./configure --prefix=$HOME CFLAGS="-arch i386 x86_64" LDFLAGS="-arch i386 x86_64" --disable-shared --with-darwinssl --without-zlib  --without-libidn --disable-ldap
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Hi. How did you manage to compile a project in Xcode with static libcurl? I built the library as you indicated, included `/usr/local/lib/libcurl.a` in **Other Linker Flags**. I get 87 undefined symbols errors. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn -- I had to look again at what I did: I create a lib folder in my Home folder (i.e. ~/lib), then put in the libcurl-x86_64.a there.  The "trick" was to put "/Users/stephen/lib" BEFORE (above) "/usr/local/lib" in the Xcode Build Setting "Library Search Paths".

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working now. Except that the libcurl.a library is not universal -- gives me errors when I am trying to compile with the 32-bit architecture. I tried to build another copy with CFLAGS="-arch i386" but to no avail... Cheers.

Comment: @IgorTupitsyn - I think you might need to have both i386 and x86_64 as params to -arch, for BOTH CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. (see my edit to my question, above)

Comment: This is really funny. It does not allow me to compile for both 32 and 64-bit. Simply does not compile. Only if I compile separately for 32 or 64-bit... Still many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I tried the approach suggested by SMGreenfield and it did not work for me. One of the reasons: the library cannot be used in the universal environment because file **curlbuild.h** is different for each architecture. Using this as a source https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2015-08/0146.html, I did the following. Have not been able to do a lot of testing yet, but the library compiled without error "**curl_rule_01 declared as an array with negative size**".

1. Build 64-bit static libcurl:

Download CURL source file to: **/Users/yourname/Libs/**.

Create folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_64**.

Type in Terminal:

```
$ cd /Users/yourname/Libs/curl-7.52.1
$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.7"
$ export CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
$ export LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_64 --disable-shared -–enable-static --without-libidn –-without-zlib -–disable-ldap
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

2. Build 32-bit static libcurl:

Create folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_32**.

Type in Terminal:

```
$ cd /Users/yourname/Libs/curl-7.52.1
$ export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.7"
$ export CFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ export LDFLAGS="-arch i386"
$ ./configure --prefix=/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_32 --disable-shared –-enable-static --without-libidn –-without-zlib -–disable-ldap
$ make clean
$ make
$ make install
```

3. Create universal libcurl:

Create folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_universal/lib**.

Lipo two static libraries:

```
lipo -create /Users/yourname/Libs/curl_32/lib/libcurl.a /Users/yourname/Libs/curl_64/lib/libcurl.a –output /Users/yourname/Libs/curl_universal/libcurl.a
```

Copy all subfolders from **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_64** to **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_universal** *except for subfolder* **lib**!

In folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_universal/include/curl** copy file **curlbuild.h** and save as **curlbuild64.h**. Copy this file from folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_32/include/curl** to folder **/Users/yourname/Libs/curl_universal/include/curl** and save it as **curlbuild32.h**. Now we should have three files: **curlbuild.h**, **curlbuild64.h**, and **curlbuild32.h**.

8. Open file **curlbuild.h** and edit as follows:

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem, this solution worked :) Thanks